# A variant of "draw without replacement" problem

Tags: probability

I've got a variant of "draw without replacement" problem:

Suppose we have $n$ urns, each of which contains $1$ good object and $c-1$ bad objects. (This implies each urn contains $c$ objects in total.) We now play a game which proceeds in rounds. In each round, you close your eyes and draw $n$ objects, each from one urn. After the draw, you open your eyes and see the objects that you have drawn. Once you find a good object, the game ends. Otherwise, you close your eyes again and proceed into next round. (Of course, the balls that have been drawn will *not* be put back.)

Now, let $x$ be a random variable which denotes the number of rounds before the game ends. The question is: what is the expectation of $x$?

I tried to do brute force calculation, but can't get anywhere... In fact, I don't need the precise answer, what I'm interested in is: in the case where $c>n$, can we show $\mathbb{E}(x)\geq\alpha c/n$, where $\alpha$ is some positive constant? (I.e., for those who are familiar with computer science, is $\mathbb{E}(x)=\Omega(c/n)$?)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$E(x)=\frac{1^n+2^n+\cdots+c^n}{c^n}\gt\frac c{n+1}$$

To see this note that $x=x_1+x_2+\cdots x_c$, where $x_k$ is an indicator variable taking the value $1$ if no success in the first $c-k$ draws, $0$ otherwise.

$$E(x)=\sum_{k=1}^cE(x_k)=\sum_{k=1}^cP(x_k=1)=\sum_{k=1}^c\left(\frac kc\right)^n$$

I guess $P(x_k=1)$ needs some explanation. Instead of urns, I like to imagine $n$ well-shuffled decks of $c$ cards, each deck containing exactly one joker. A round consists of taking the top card from each deck; the game ends when a joker is drawn. Now $x_k=1$ is the event that no joker is drawn in the first $c-k$ rounds, i.e., every joker is in the bottom $k$ cards of its respective deck. Clearly, the probability of that is $(\frac kc)^n$. (The term $E(x_c)=1$ corresponds to the fact at least the first round is sure to take place.)

The inequality on the first line follows from the fact that
$$\sum_{k=1}^c\left(\frac kc\right)^n\frac1c\gt\int_0^1x^ndx=\frac1{n+1}.$$

Comment: Nice approach to use indicator random variable (i.r.v.)! But it seems there are some error... For the ease of convenience, let $x_i$ be i.r.v. which takes value $1$ iff no success in the first $i$ rounds. Then, as you wrote, we have $\mathbb{E}(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{c}{\mathbb{E}(x_i)}$. The problem is, the probability that $x_i=1$ is not $(k/c)^n$. Instead, I think it is $\Pi_{j=1}^{i}{\left(1-\frac{1}{c-(j-1)}\right)^n}$. (E.g., the chance you fail the first round is $1-(1/c)^n$, and the probability that you fail the first two rounds is $(1-(1/c)^n)(1-(1/(c-1))^n)$.

Comment: Now, we can simplify $\Pi_{j=1}^{i}{\left(1-\frac{1}{c-(j-1)}\right)^n}$ into $\left(1-\frac{1}{c-(i-1)}\right)^n$. Hence, $\mathbb{E}(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{c}{\left(1-\frac{1}{c-(i-1)}\right)^n}=\sum_{i=2}^{c}{\left(1-\frac{1}{i}\right)^n}$. So, here comes the new question, how to simply the last summation...

Comment: If you define $x_i$ to be the indicator variable for "no success in the first $i$ rounds" then you have to sum from $i=0$ to $c-1$, not $1$ to $c$.

Comment: The probability that you fail on the first round is $(1-\frac1c)^n$ not $1-(\frac1c)^n$. Unless I really misunderstood the question. You stop when you draw *one* good object, right?

Comment: For example, if $n=c=2$, the probability of failing on the first round is $\frac14$, not $\frac34$, right??

Comment: Yes, you are right. I've made several mistakes along the way... Our calculation should lead to the same results. I will make some summary and clarification: (I) If define $x_i$ to be i.r.v. for "no success in first $i$ rounds", then sum should be taken from $1$ to $c-1$. In fact, $\mathbb{E}(x_c)$ is always $0$, so it does not matter if we take it into consideration or not. As for the case $i=0$, I don't think we should take it into consideration, as it does not seem to make sense.

Comment: (II) The probability that we fail on the first round is $(1-1/c)^n$. I made a typo when typing the example, sorry. Nevertheless, the expression that $\mathbb{P}(x_i=1)=\Pi_{j=1}^{i}{\left(1-\frac{1}{c-(j-1)}\right)^n}$ is correct. In particular, it should be simplified into $(1-i/c)^n$, not the one listed above, this is another mistake I made...

Comment: (III) Now, sum up all the $x_i$, we have $\mathbb{E}(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{c-1}{(1-i/c)^n}=\sum_{i=1}^{c-1}{(i/c)^n}$, which is the same as your expression. Notice, I ignore the case "fail in the first $0$ rounds", which is included in your expression.

Comment: Finally, would you mind to explain the inequality you wrote, i.e., why $\sum_{i=1}^{c}{(i/c)^n}>c/(n+1)$? I know this should be some classical result, but can you please point out some references? Thanks!

Comment: I added a line of explanation for the inequality. $\sum_{i=1}^c(i/c)^n$ is correct, $\sum_{i=1}^{c-1}(i/c)^n$ is wrong, as you can see by looking at a small case like $n=1$ and $c=1$ or $c=2$. Omitting the term $(c/c)^n=1$ amounts to not counting the first round, which must always take place, because you will certainly not have obtained a "good object" after $0$ rounds.